# Angular - IE8 ng-option selects the wrong value

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I am having a problem using Angular's (1.2.7) ng-option function with I.E 8..

The functionality works but when the client user selects an option, the value selected is one below the one that was clicked.

The code is using this prebuilt array ***values changed**

```
        ourArray = ["", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"],
```

And we are displaying the data like so :

```
                    name="ourSelect"
                    class="form-control"
                    ng-model="select.number"
                    ng-change="ourArray.function()"
                    ng-options="num for num in ourArray"
```

Like I say, when we select an option in IE8 it is selecting the value below the one that was clicked. So if we click value #2 value #3 is selected..

This only happens in IE 8 and I can't find anyone else who has had a similar issue.

And sadly, yes we do have to support IE8

Comment: what is going on in that ng-change ourArray.function() ? that looks strange

Comment: Ignore that I had to alter it as the code it is client sensitive

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with the ng-options directive before. Try using ng-repeat manually instead:

```
<select name="ourSelect" class="form-control" ng-model="select.number" ng-change="ourArray.function()">
  <option value="{{num}}" ng-repeat="num in ourArray">{{num}}</option>
</select>
```